# Execute a system command from C#

Tags: c#, windows

My program must be executed immediately after Windows's login screen. For this purpose, I have changed some registry values and now this program launches on start-up instead of Explorer.exe (). In my program, users enter their username and password and then login to system. After login, I want to run explorer.exe, taskbar, and start menu to become visible to user. I use this code to execute system command:

```
string cmd = "/C explorer.exe ";
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", cmd);
```

But after executing this command, just the `My Computer` window appears. Taskbar and Start Menu do not appear. How can I see Taskbar and Start Menu after executing the `explorer.exe` command (I use Windows 7)?

Comment: *I have changed some registry values* Please expand so that we have some idea what you have done

Comment: Also, you can just do `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("explorer.exe")`. No need to use CMD to start explorer...

Comment: Er, this sounds rather dangerous to me. What do you need to do after logon, before any Windows process actually kick in?

Comment: My suspicion is that you have made your program be the shell. You can do that, but you need to face up to your responsibilities and actually be a shell. You can't change your mind later and expect explorer to save you.

Comment: Why did you replace the desktop shell if you still want the normal shell to be present? Creating a new desktop shell is vastly more work than just making a windows application. If you don't know how, or want to do all that work, you should not make a shell. Instead you should create a service and react to user logging on.

Answer (score 1):

The proper (and only!) way to do customized login is via the Credentials Provider (post Vista) or using Gina (pre-Vista). Read [Create Custom Login Experiences With Credential Providers For Windows Vista](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163489.aspx) for an explanation how to do it.

Right now your are just feeding the future columns of [Raymond Chen](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/) about misbehaving apps.